# DAQmxConfigurLogging C API

Tags: daq-mx

I use the NI-PCI 6225 card.

I want to read the 1000 samples with the time of each sample. I used

DAQmxConfigurLogging C API, but in the TDMS file that was generated, there was no time for each sample.

What should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a continuous or finite acquisition. If that's the case, the TDMS file will store a waveform, which has three properties:

- The start time (`t0`) -- this is the wall-time of the first sample
- The sample period (`delta_t`) -- this is the time between each sample
- The array of `samples` -- these are measured values

To get a time for each sample, use this formula:

```
time_at_sample_n = t0 + (n * delta_t)
```